# Iterate through an list of objects and run a function for each - Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm wondering for the simplest method for how to run a specific function for each object in an array (or other list type)

My goal is to be able create a list of objects, and have each object run a specific function as it passes through the iterator.

I've tried a for loop on an arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++)
    {
        this  = textList.get(i);
        this.exampleFunction();
    }
```

But this gives me a 'Variable expected' error

Comment: A loop? (`for` loop) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @GBlodgett I had accidentally submitted before finishing, I have tried a for loop

Comment: `Foo foo = textList.get(i); foo.function();`

Comment: In what context is this? What is `this.function`?

Comment: this.function()  ?

Comment: Btw, `this` is a keyword. Calling `function` method is `function()`.

Comment: @GBlodgett I am making a game engine and dont feel like manually adding each object's .render and .update functions, I wanted to create a handler that would save  me time

Comment: @AyoubLaazazi and Jai I have fixed my typo, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The problem in your example is the dangling `this` in `this = …` @LouisWasserman's comment shows a way that should work

Comment: @LouisWasserman It's telling me I cant reference my function from a static context. I am trying to create this list from within the class that the list will be holding object of. Am I supposed to make the list outside the class?

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword in Java. Don't use `this` as variable name. Calling method is done with `()` at the end of method name.

Comment: What function are you trying to call?  It might be static when it shouldn't be, or vice versa.  Are you calling `foo.function()` instead of `this.function()` like I said above?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have everything it asks of me static. It complies, but it crashes when ever I get to the code that section that executes my code. https://pastebin.com/ZwmMGrhW Would you please take a look at this class. All the relevant parts are commented. How do I add the object to the list in the constructor?

Comment: `textList` should _not_ be static, and you haven't initialized it at all, e.g. `textList = new ArrayList<TextManager>();`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you very much for your feedback, albeit, I do have a followup. Wouldn't doing that just create a new ArrayList each time I create a new object from this class?

Comment: Yes, as it almost certainly should.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Also, it's static because when  I call it in the class that con trols the screen, I'm calling it as TextManager.renderList(), which requires it to be static. How do I implement this properly.

Comment: Whatever is calling `renderList` should be defining `textList`, then, initializing and filling it, and passing it as another argument to `renderList`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I solved my problem. I implemented a singleton ListManager. It does exactly what I wanted. Honestly, I'm not sure why it took me this long to come to this conclusion. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, and you have a `Collection<TypeInList>` you could call [`Collection.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) and do a `forEach` on that. Like,

```
testList.stream().forEach(TypeInList::function);
```

Your current approach is trying to do things with `this` that cannot be done. It could be fixed like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++)
{
    TypeInList that = testList.get(i); // this is a reserved word.
    that.function();
}
```

**or**

```
for (TypeInList x : testList) {
    x.function();
}
```

Comment: No need for `stream()`.  Iterable (and therefore every Collection) has [its own forEach method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach%28java.util.function.Consumer%29).

Comment: This compiles, but it crashes when I try to reach the part where this section executes.

Comment: Crashes in what way?  Is there a stack trace?  Some kind of error message?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'm too inexperienced to know what a stack trace is, and no error message. I've actually narrowed it down, his example is fine, it's my own code that is faulty. How do I add an object to the list as part of the constructor? Using .add(this) is what was causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to iterate through a list, but the easiest I personally find is like this:

Assuming that your list contains String objects e.g.:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hello");
list.add("World");

for(String current : list){
    System.out.println(current);
}
```

The loop will iterate twice, and console will output the following:

```
Hello
World
```

This approach doesn't rely on indexes (as how you're using it in your question), as such I find it easy to use for iterating through a single list.

However the disadvantage is that if you have 2 separate lists that you would like to iterate through, the lack of indexes makes it a bit more complicated. The easier approach for iterating through multiple lists would be using the traditional approach, something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    int x = list1.get(i);
    int y = list2.get(i);
}
```

As such your use-case really determines the ideal method you can adopt.